# Creating a child process WITHOUT fork()

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, child-process, execvp

Is there a way to start a child process without `fork()`, using `execvp()` exclusively?

Comment: Yes, if the process created by `execvp` is using `fork` or `clone`... This question makes no sense without rationale provided.

Comment: `execvp` replaces your process with another executable so hardly a *child* process. Why the resistance to `fork`?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no rational behind the question because there is this specific restriction on my project.

Comment: If you have a restriction on using `fork` then you are not supposed to create a child process, that's it. Or maybe they want you to use `clone`.

Comment: Creating a child process is a non negotiable demand according to the instructions given by the professor. `execvp` only!

Comment: Could you please quote us the full statement of restrictions on your project?  It's possible you are supposed to learn something subtle about Unix from discovering that you _can't_ start a child process without `fork`, but it's also possible that you misunderstood the assignment.

Comment: Then either you have misunderstood the assignment or the professor is asking for impossible.

Comment: execvp doesn't create a new process, it runs a new program in the context of your current process.

Comment: What is the operating system? There are plenty of operating systems that do not use fork() at all.

Comment: man vfork(); or if you wanted to be even more disingenuous, system().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pedantic answer to your question is no.  The *only* system call that creates a new process is `fork`.  The system call underlying `execvp` (called `execve`) loads a new *program* into an existing process, which is a different thing.

Some species of Unix have additional system calls besides `fork` (e.g. `vfork`, `rfork`, `clone`) that create a new process, but they are only small variations on `fork` itself, and none of them are part of the POSIX standard that specifies the functionality you can count on on *anything* that calls itself a Unix.

The slightly more helpful answer is that you might be looking for `posix_spawn`, which is a library routine wrapping `fork` and `exec` into a single operation, but I find it *more* troublesome to use that correctly than to write my own `fork`+`exec` subroutine.  YMMV.

Comment: @DanO I don't think that makes enough of a difference to change my answer. Sure, `posix_spawn` might be using a newer fork-with-options primitive, whatever that's called, rather than the original fork(2), but it's still a library routine that wraps a fork operation and an exec operation. Its *algorithm* has not changed.

Comment: @DanO please reread the second paragraph of the answer: clone has been mentioned since I originally wrote it. Since clone is just a small variation on fork, its existence doesn't invalidate my original point, no more than vfork does.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't see it. As long as posix_spawn is implemented by doing a fork _operation_ and an exec _operation_, I think what the answer currently says is accurate. The names of the system calls involved are not important.

Comment: You're insisting on a distinction that, as far as I can tell, does not correspond to an actual difference. Clone performs a fork operation.

Comment: I'll write my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike Windows systems, where creating a new process and executing a new process image happen in a single step, Linux and other UNIX-like systems do them as two distinct steps.

The `fork` function makes an exact duplicate of the calling process and actually returns twice, once to the parent process and once to the child process.  The `execvp` function (and other functions in the `exec` family) executes a new process image in the same process, overwriting the existing process image.

You can call `execvp` without calling `fork` first.  If so, that just means the currently running program goes away and is replaced with the given program.  However, `fork` is **the way** to create a new process.

Comment: **overwriting the existing process image** going into implementation details I'd imagine it's done lazy and only the page tables are replaced at first with the registers.

Answer (score 3):

[posix_spawn](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) is the only posix compliant way to create a child process without calling `fork` directly. I say 'directly' because historically `posix_spawn` would itself just call `fork`, or `vfork`. However, that is no longer the case in GNU/linux. `posix_spawn` itself may be more efficient than `fork`, in addition to perhaps being a stronger fit conceptually when code is attempting to run a different executable.

If you aren't worried about portability, you can abandon posix and couple yourself directly to the kernel you are targeting. On linux the system call to create a child process is [clone](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html). At the time of this answer the manual page provides documentation for three variants, including the relatively new `clone3`.

I believe you can take the example from the manual page and add an `execvp` call to `childFunc`. I have not tried it yet, though!

Comment: *However, that is no longer the case in GNU/linux. `posix_spawn` itself may be more efficient than `fork`*  The reason is [`fork()` is broken in glibc](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4737) and glibc maintainers have been waging a decade-and-a-half effort to get `fork()` removed from the POSIX list of async-signal-safe functions.

Answer (score 1):

As user zwol has already explained, `execve()` does not fork a new process. Rather, it replaces the address space and CPU state of *current* process,
loads the new address space from the executable filename and starts it from
`main()` with argument list `argv` and environment variable list `envp`.
It keeps pid and open files.

```
int execve(const char *filename,char *const argv [],char *const envp[]);
```

`filename`: name of executable file to run
`argv`: Command line arguments
`envp`: environment variable settings (e.g., `$PATH`, `$HOME`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

posix_spawn. But it ignores failures of execvp() -- potentially because implementing this was regarded as too complicated.